# lumen route gives duplicated prefix

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Redirect:

```
return redirect()->route('login', ['token' => $token]);
```

Route:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'super/v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($app) {
    $app->get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@login']);
}
```

When I try to redirect to login like the example above, it returns duplicated prefix in my url:

> http://localhost:8080/super/v1/super/v1/login?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi

What I need is this url:

> http://localhost:8080/super/v1/login?token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi

I only have one group in my routes! No nested routes!
Thank you.

Comment: `localhost` is the server running locally, i.e. *on your computer*. We don't have access to it, so no one else here can see either what's going on or what you're trying to get

Comment: I am getting /super/v1/super/v1 but what I want is /super/v1! The prefix is being duplicated after the redirect!! Theres no need to access it!

Comment: Okay, this question came up in the triage queue and it was unclear that what you're trying to fix is only the URL itself and not any sort of rendered content

Comment: Im sorry for that! I updated my question!!